# Data have not been inserted to database collected through WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am a new in flask and flask-sqlalchemy. The problem is when entering new record (venue) through wtforms, the flash message flashes **success**, however, the data not inserted to database. I need your help please.

The POST route:
import json
import dateutil.parser
import babel
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from forms import *
from models import db, Venue, Artist, Show
import sys

```
app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment(app)
app.config.from_object('config')

# TODO: connect to a local postgresql database

db.init_app(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_venue_submission():
  error = False
  form = VenueForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    venue=Venue(name=form.name.data,
                city=form.city.data,
                state=form.state.data,
                address=form.address.data,
                phone=form.phone.data,
                image_link=form.image_link.data,
                genres=form.genres.data,
                facebook_link=form.facebook_link.data)
    form.populate_obj(venue)
    db.session.add(venue)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('forms/new_venue.html'))
  if not error:
    flash('Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' was successfully listed!')
  if error:
  # TODO: on unsuccessful db insert, flash an error instead.
    flash('An error occurred. Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' could not be listed.')
  return render_template('pages/home.html', form=form)
```

The model code snippets:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()
class Venue(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'venues'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
city = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
state = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
address = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
website = db.Column(db.String(120))
    
def __repr__(self):
  return f'<Venue id: {self.id}, name: {self.name}>'
```

The success message in backend:

[backend status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8KP2.png)

The success message in frontend:
[front end flash message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EZ6C.png)

The database status:

[database status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI0yj.png)

This is very confusing and can't find where is the problem.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never fail your error check— you set `error=False` at the top of the function, but no code within your function can flip it to `error=True`, so `if not error:` is always going to run, sending a successful message.

I suspect, without seeing your code— that the form is failing validation (if you're new, you may have forgotten the `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in your form template?) and so none of that form reading/database insertion actually happens.

Comment: You are correct, so how can make the form successfully validated ?

Comment: `form.errors` will indicate what's caused the `form.validate_on_submit()` to fail

Comment: Thanks for your support. I added this check:
`if form.errors != {}: #If there are not errors from the validations
      for err_msg in form.errors.values():
          flash(f'There was an error with creating a venue: {err_msg}')`
I got this error: There was an error with creating a venue: ['Invalid URL.']
However I checked URLs as shown in above code and found that nothing wired

Comment: `['Invalid URL.']` is telling you the URL entered into the form isn't in the expected format-- It expects something like `https://www.google.com` (`localhost` will fail unless you turned off the tld requirement). https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.URL

Comment: Finally it works, I really appreciate your support